# Setting a folder to be ignored, must I commit this change/modification?

Tags: svn, ignore, svn-propset

Sorry, this is probably a daft question, but I am having a slow day.

I have a folder:

```
wp-content/uploads/
```

I would like all files and folders within /uploads/ to be ignored by svn. But I don't want them to be deleted as they are needed for the website to work.

The contents of /uploads/ were not in version control, i.e. they were not checked in so I did the following in the terminal:

```
$ cd /wp-content/uploads/
$ svn propset svn:ignore '*'  .
```

So now when I check the status of svn using `svn status` I get the following:

```
M     wp-content/uploads
```

So now my question, since it says "M", do I need to commit wp-content/uploads ?

If I do, will it commit the actual folder **contents** or simply the **property** that has been set? I don't want the contents to be committed. But committing the property would make sense.

At this point I am just unsure about what exactly will be committed if I do `svn commit /wp-contents/uploads/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you must to commit your modified Working Copy (modified because changing properties also is part of history, which SVN-repository have to save and manage)

If content of `/wp-contents/uploads/` was not added to SVN (and files was shown with '?' status before), then *now*, even before committing changed property, all ? must just disappear from `svn status` and files (exising and will added later) become "invisible" to SVN

`svn commit /wp-contents/uploads/` will commit (*as intended*) only property-change for versioned folder (properties are the same first-class citizens for SVN as files and folders)